# What is the best way to model complex nested objects in Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to Firebase and would like some help regarding modeling my data in the document. I have a background in SQL so using Firebase feels so unrestricted and open (IDK how else to describe this). I am working on a personal project and need to use Firebase. The project is my personal note-taking app.

here is the hierarchy that I am trying to make:

Label

```
class Label {
  String label;
  List<Category> categories;
}
```

Category

```
class Category{
  String category;
  List<Note> notes;
}
```

Note

```
class Note{
  String title;
  String note;
}
```

I had got this working in SQLite but it was only offline so i had to switch to Firebase.

So far i have tried:

1. Having 3 separate collections of label, category and note. I couldn't get it to have relations between the 3 collections.
2. Having 1 single collection called data which would container this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6WYF.png)
3. Having 1 collection of labels with sub-collections in it of categories and then Categories having sub-collection of notes.

I am really stuck here. Each of them is not ideal to work with and I didn't think I would say this, but I miss SQL so much right now. Any Firebase experts that know what route I should take?

Comment: In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for the info, so basically i would be performing the CRUD operations on all 3 of these objects. - SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE labelId = 2 (example) type stuff and then also writing update/delete queries on it.

Comment: I'm not asking about updating and deleting, but only about reading. I'm not sure I understand what `SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE labelId = 2` exactly means. Can you please be more specific.

Comment: @AlexMamo my apologies. For getting the data, i want to get all the labels (this parts easy) then after i select a label on my app i get all the categories that fall under that label (this is where i face the most problems). After selecting a category,  i will get all notes under that category (problems here too). I need to know the best way to structure this data in this hierarchy. Thanks again.

Comment: What is the exact relationship between label, category, and note?

Comment: @AlexMamo So basically, label will have list of categories(can be an empty list too) and category will have list of notes (can be empty list too). The object above state the relationship too.

Comment: So you only want to get all categories that have set a particular label, as well as all notes of a particular category. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlexMamo That is correct sir.

Answer (score 0):

In the NoSQL world, we are usually a database according to the queries that we want to perform. Now, understanding that you need to get all categories that have set a particular label, as well as all notes of a particular category, then please check the following [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) schema:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- categories (collection)
  |     |
  |     --- $categoryId (document)
  |            |
  |            --- label: "labelOne"
  |            |
  |            --- name: "categoryName"
  |
  --- notes (collection)
        |
        --- $noteyId (document)
               |
               --- category: "categoryName"
               |
               --- name: "categoryName"
```

In this way, both queries will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Hey, shreyy. Have you tried my solution above, does it work? Or can I help you with other information?